# Writing a function that returns true if given string has exactly 6 characters

Tags: algorithm, sorting, duplicates, ascii

I am trying to write a function that returns true or false if a given string has **exactly**  6 consecutive characters with the same value. If the string has more or less than 6, it will return false:

I **am not allowed to use lists, sets or import any packages.** I am only restricted to while loops, for loops, and utilizing basic mathematical operations

Two example runs are shown below:

```
Enter a string: 367777776  
True
```

```
Enter a string: 3677777777776  
False
```

Note that although I entered numbers, it is actually a string within the function argument for example: `consecutive('3777776')`

I tried to convert the string into an ASCII table and then try and filter out the numbers there. However, I

```
def consecutive(x):
    storage= ' '
    acc=0
    count=0
    for s in x:
        storage+= str(ord(s)) + ' '
        acc+=ord(s)
        if acc == acc:
            count+=1
    for s in x-1:
        
    return count
```

My intention is to compare the previous character's ASCII code  to the current character's ASCII code in the string. If the ASCII doesnt match, I will add an accumulator for it. The accumulator will list the number of duplicates. From there, I will implement an if-else statement to see if it is greater or less than 6 However, I have a hard time translating my thoughts into python code.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: If you were allowed imports, then `from itertools import groupby; def consecutive(x): return any(len(g) == 6 for _,g in groupby(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty good start!

A few comments:

- Variables `storage` and `acc` play the same role, and are a little more complicated than they have to be. All you want to know when you arrive at character `s` is whether or not `s` is identical to the previous character. So, you only need to store the previously seen character.
- Condition `acc == acc` is always going to be True. I think you meant `acc == s`?
- When you encounter an identical character, you correctly increase the count with `count += 1`. However, when we change characters, you should reset the count.

With these comments in mind, I fixed your code, then blanked out a few parts for you to fill. I've also renamed `storage` and `acc` to `previous_char` which I think is more explicit.

```py
def has_6_consecutive(x):
    previous_char = None
    count = 0
    for s in x:
        if s == previous_char:
            ???
        elif count == 6:
            ???
        else:
            ???
            previous_char = ???
    ???
```

Comment: how do you iterate through the previous_char?  I have  some trouble filing in the last 2 question marks

Comment: @myts999 The current char is `s`. The previous char is `previous_char`. At the very end of the current iteration, the current char becomes the previous char to prepare for the next iteration. So, the last thing we do in an iteration is `previous_char = ...`?

Comment: Okay. Now correct me if I'm wrong but the first question mark is ```count+=1```, the second one is return True, third one is ```count= 0```, 4th one is ```previous_char= s```, last one is ```return False?```

Comment: @myts999 first one, second one, fourth one are correct. Third and last are wrong.

Comment: @myts999 `return False` at the end is almost correct. I guess you can write that for the moment; then try to test the function with a lot of different strings and you might find one of them where the return value is not correct.

Comment: @myts999 `count = 0` is the correct idea, but...

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion. Loop over all the characters and for each one check to see of the next 6 are identical. If so, return true. If you get to the end of the array (or even within 6 characters of the end), return false.

For more info on recursion, check this out: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

Comment: I cant use recursion because it hasnt been taught

Answer (score 0):

would something like this be allowed?

```py
def consecF(n):
    consec = 1
    prev = n[0]
    for i in n:
        if i==prev:
            consec+=1
        else:
            consec=1
        if consec == 6:
            return True
        prev = i
        
    return False
n = "12111123333221"
print(consecF(n))
```

Comment: This returns True for `'1111111'`, but I think the OP wants it to return False (because there is a run of 7 consecutive, not 6).

Comment: Anyhow, I don't think writing a complete solution is really a good way to help the OP learn.

Comment: @Stef oh well, since i did it wrong it's not a complete solution anyway :p

Comment: @Stef but also if it needs to be exactly 6, another if statement could be added to handle when it's more than 6 (before the second if) if consec >6: consec = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try a two pointer approach, where the left pointer is fixed at the first instance of some digit and the right one is shifted as long as the digit is seen.

```
def consecutive(x):
    left = 0
    while left != len(x):
        right = left
        while right < len(x) and x[right] == x[left]:
            right += 1
        length = (right - 1) - left + 1 # from left to right - 1 inclusive, x[left] repeated
        if length == 6: # found desired length
            return True
            
        left = right

    return False # no segment found
     
tests = [
    '3677777777776',
    '367777776'
]

for test in tests:
    print(f"{test}: {consecutive(test)}")
```

Output

```
3677777777776: False
367777776: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the *current sequence of repeated chars*.

```
def consecutive(x):
    sequencechar = ' '
    repetitions = 0
    for ch in x:
        if ch != sequencechar:
            if repetitions == 6:
                break
            sequencechar = ch
            repetitions = 1
        else:
            repetitions += 1
    return repetitions == 6
```

If I could, I would not have given the entire solution, but this still is a simple problem. However one has to take care of some points.

As you see the current sequence is stored, and when the sequence is ended and a new starts, on having found a correct sequence it breaks out of the for loop.

Also after the for loop ends normally, the last sequence is checked (which was not done in the loop).